# SSIS send mail task is completing but not sending any files

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2015, smtp

Having an issue with this particular series.  This has run perfectly fine for a number of years.  Currently I am testing to see if I can get this file sent out to myself but I am coming up short. Basically this will show as completed, will continue to the next phase and move to the sent folder.  However no mail is getting delivered.  There is a expression and constraint tied to the success of "Check if File Exists in Root" where if this is true then it will continue on based on multiple constraints of Logical AND.  Any and all help will be appreciated.

[image: Mail Fail]

Edit: Adding in visual of how the mail task is configured.

[image: Initial set up]

[image]

Comment: ***If*** the task isn't failing then that would suggest that the problem is elsewhere, such as the mail server is accepting the mail, but then not sending it afterwards or the target address has blocked the email. Have you checked your junk?

Comment: Also, would be helpful to see how you have send mail task configured + the expressions you have on the task. If you remove the requirement to send an attachment, does an email get sent?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. Does the send mail work if you exclude the attachments? If you run the package from a server instead of your desktop, does it fare any better? Are you working with a local mail server or is this a cloud hosted mail server?